# Can't return specific nested class property

Tags: c#

I made a class for deserialize a JSON (I'm using JSON.net), this is the structure:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set;}
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I deserialize the JSON like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
```

Now If I want return all the JSON I simply do: `return obj.Users;` but how can I return a specific property of the class `User`? In particular the `Name` property. I tried this:

```
return obj.Users.name // user list does not contain any name property
```

Also I tried with LINQ:

```
obj.Select(c => c.Name).Single();
```

But I can't use `Select` because I need to declare `obj` as:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(responseText);
```

If instead I return `obj.user;` I can use LINQ and access to the name. But how can do this in the method that return the response?

Comment: Does `RootObject.user` contain a single user or multiple users? which user name would you want to return if it contains multiple users?

Comment: for which User you want to send property value? RootObject contains user list

Comment: @YacoubMassad in this case user contain a list of one item, but in other case there is multiple items.

Comment: every User has a member of Users (list) and it is a List<T>. So you should access list member [] or with linq methods. It is not question of Json or serialization. it just a basic c# array using.

Comment: @NuriYILMAZ yes I know this, but I'm learning c# so for some concepts I need an help. Thanks.

Comment: @IlDrugo Could you please mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: @M.S. Sure, I have to wait the stackoverflow accepted answer time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to class

```
 using System.Linq;
```

since user is of type List you can apply lambda expression in it. Do not use `Single` it will fail if `user` will have more than one record in it, use `FirstOrDefault` instead. It will work for zero or more number of elements

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
string name = obj.user.Select(p=> p.name).FirstOrDefault();
string surname = obj.user.Select(p=> p.surname).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @IIDrugo, I think thats the correct way to get the property of user

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *one*  user instead of the whole list as `RootObject.user` is a `List<User>` and not an instance of `User`:

```
var name = obj[0].Name;
```

Or whatever element within your list you want to use.

Alternativly use LINQ:

```
var user = obj.FirstOrDefault();
if (user != null) name = user.name;
```